# Is there a non-obvious connection between nuclear stability of iron and ferromagnetism?

Tags: nuclear-physics, ferromagnetism

I find it quite remarkable that iron is the most stable nucleus, as well as the most important technical material. While its nuclear stability naturally implies that it is the most abundant material on earth (due to the process of cosmological nucleosynthesis), and hence, one might argue that we just used what we found readily available in nature, other aspects of the technological role of iron are not so easily explained.

While I can hardly imagine that the outstanding mechanical strength properties of iron/steel are somehow related to its nuclear properties, I am not so sure if there is not possibly a relation between nuclear stability and ferromagnetism. Most of the ferromagnetic elements (Fe, Co, Ni) happen to occur close to A=58. Does nuclear stability also result in something special with respect to nuclear spin? Is the coupling of nuclear spin and electronic spin of any significance in ferromagnetism?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [nuclear shell model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_shell_model)? You get *some*  numerical patterns in nuclear shells corresponding to those in electron shells, leading to "coincidences" like the noble gas nuclei being fairly stable. But it would be a mistake to claim that the nuclear stability causes the chemical stability (or vice versa).

Comment: I find it a bit subjective, to search "most stable" periodic element. All elements are stable which has half-life of $t_{1/2} = \infty$. Such are many. On the other hand, every element which has nucleon amount $n \gt 1$ is subject to nucleus breakdown, in case of capturing or loosing some of neutrons. In this sense most stable elements are Hydrogen and Helium. You can't divide Hydrogen nuclei at all, because it just has 1 proton in nuclei. That's why $98 \%$ of matter is composed of H,He atoms. There are known **24** [radioactive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_iron) iron isotopes.

Comment: Given that the Curie temperature of Fe (or Co or Ni) is within normal human experience, unlike temperatures (energies) of relevance to nuclear forces, the simple answer is that there is no connection between ferromagnetism and stability of the nucleus.

Comment: Second argument that there is no relationship between nucleus stability and ferromagnetism is that ferromagnetism comes from the alignment of electron spin,  however nucleus stability has something to do with inter-nuclear forces between nucleons, which has nothing to do with electron features. You can relatively easily destroy electron spin state, but you can not do "easy changes" in nucleus configuration.